# Vultures Mirrors is allowed?

Tags: discussion

Today I realized that google shows me original results from stackoverflow, but in answersresource.wordpress.com and stackanswers.com

What seems to me is that they are vultures who are looking for ad-clicks.

Not undermine the purpose of StackOverflow? 
StackExchange policies allow this?

Example:

[How to send cookies from angular mock backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402956/how-to-send-cookies-from-angular-mock-backend)

http://answersresource.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-send-cookies-from-angular-mock-backend/

http://stackanswers.com/questions/26402956/how-to-send-cookies-from-angular-mock-backend

Comment: Report them to Stack Exchange: [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)